# Definite integral over the plane

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck with the following exercise:

$$\iint{ e ^ {(-x^2-y^2-axy)} dx dy}$$
for $x,y \in (-\infty, +\infty)$.

I have tried with polar coordinates and I got

$$\iint{ \rho e ^ {-\rho^2(1+\frac{a}{2} \sin(2\phi))} d\rho d\phi}$$

integrating rho I get
[image]

The problem is that integrating phi over [0, 2pi] gives

[image]

My textbook says that the integral value is $$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}}}$$

What did I miss?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170885).

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician really interesting.. but how should I proceed then?

Comment: The point of that link was that your last integration gave an antiderivative that is not continuous over $[0,2\pi]$. The answers below have already shown you other ways to proceed.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician so the conclusion is: "you cannot integrate this way, find other ideas"?

Comment: More or less. In the link, I derived an antiderivative that is continuous over the real line for that case, but that is too high-powered to use here, and the two excellent approaches you've been given proceed much more smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we can evaluate the integral in Cartesian coordinates directly.  We proceed by writing

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2-axy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2(1-a^2/4)}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+ay/2)^2}\,dx\right)\,dy\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2(1-a^2/4)}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\,dy\\\\
&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2(1-a^2/4)}\,dy\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt \pi \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2(1-a^2/4)}\,dy\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt \pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2/4}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4-a^2}}
\end{align}$$

---

If one prefers to transform to polar coordinates, then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2-axy}\,dx\,dy&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^\infty \rho e^{-\rho^2(1+a\sin(2\phi)/2)}\,d\rho\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(2\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_{0}^{4\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac12 \left(\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\\\\+\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi+\int_{3\pi}^{4\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi\right)\\\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi+\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2-a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi
\end{align}$$

The integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2+a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{1}{2-a\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi$ can be evaluated using either contour integration or the tangent half-angle substitution with the result giving the expected result.

Comment: thanks a lot but how should I choose the correct manipulation?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: What did you mean by "choose the correct manipulation?"

Comment: the way you splitted the exponent..

Comment: @Surfer, completing the square is one thing to try first when confronted with a quadratic.

Comment: Note that $x^2+y^2+2axy=(x+ay/2)^2-(a^2/4)y^2$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thaaanks! the point is exactly this "split the integration region appropriately". Could you tell me in this case how should I split it?

Comment: @Surfer, if you'll recall the Weierstrass substitution that is commonly used for such integrals, the problem is that $\tan$ is discontinuous at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$, so you need to add something to compensate. That was the other point of the link I gave in the comments to your question.

Comment: Yes, sure.  We need to ensure that the half-angle substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$ is one-to-one.

Comment: As an amusing addendum: $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}}}\left(x+\arctan\left(\frac{a \cos (2 x)}{2 \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}}+a \sin (2 x)+2}\right)\right)$$ is a continuous antiderivative of $\frac1{1+a\sin x\cos x}$, but you don't really need to know that to do this integral.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician And that circumvents the splitting of the integral.  So (+1)

Comment: I didn't "double the integral."  I exploited periodicity.  What do you mean please?

Comment: sorry, I meant the interval. Could you explain the last step you added? Why did those four integrals turn into the last two?

Comment: @Surfer, since $\sin$ is $2\pi$-periodic, and you're integrating over $[0,4\pi]$, then the integral over $[0,2\pi]$ and $[2\pi,4\pi]$ is the same, no?

Comment: Well, on the principal branch of the arctangent function, we have $|\arctan(x)|\le \pi/2$.  So, enforcing the substitution $t=\tan(\phi/2)$, we need $\phi \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: [THIS ANSWER](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733962/why-is-this-definite-integral-wrong/1734042#1734042) might be useful in understanding the arctangent function.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but an easier strategy: Rotate the plane one-eighth of a turn (to diagonalize the quadratic form) before integrating. That is, write $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x + y)$ and $v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x - y)$, so that $x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u + v)$, $y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(u - v)$, and
$$
x^{2} + y^{2} + axy = (1 + \tfrac{a}{2}) u^{2} + (1 - \tfrac{a}{2}) v^{2}.
$$

Comment: hmm how did you choose the angle?

Comment: @surfer, usually when one has an $xy$ term, you try a $45^\circ$ rotation first (it's the easiest to do), and maybe something else if that doesn't work. Did you happen to study conic sections in your previous courses?

Comment: By recognizing that the eigenspaces of a quadratic form $A(x^{2} + y^{2}) + B(xy)$ are the lines $y = \pm x$. ;)